# Swipe back and forth between a number of DialogFragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

I've been trying to write code which will allow me to swipe back and forth between 3 DialogFragment views which overlay the main Activity.

To be more specific, each view should be swipeable from left to right and vice versa across the entire UI, in much the same way as fragments are in a ViewPager (with limits set at the bounds like so | 1 <--> 2 <--> 3 |) . Like fragments in ViewPager, each DialogFragment should come to rest in a natural position at the centre of the screen after swiping, and the transition animation should be similar.

Ideally, the layout and functionality would be similar to the respective defaults of a DialogFragment overlaying an activity.

Initially, I attempted this with a ViewPager but ran into trouble as the fragments didn't display with the intended layout. The main problem I had here was that the ViewPager stretched the layout of the DialogFragment across the entire UI. Furthermore, the only option I found for resizing the layout of the fragment was to limit the boundaries of the ViewPager, but of course this meant that the transitions occurred in an area smaller than the UI rather than across the entire UI. Mike's provided a brief explanation why this happens in the comments below.

I've also attempted a different approach of creating a child DialogFragment within blank ViewPager fragments. However, so far I've been unsuccessful as the ViewPager functionalilty isn't operational while the child DialogFragment is visible.

In the case of a 'work around' solution things that I want to mimic from the DialogFragment view include:

- The shadowed / darkened background outside of the DialogFragment view.
- The ability to tap outside of DialogFragment view to close the DialogFragment view (and by extension the ViewPager) and return to the main activity.

Comment: `ViewPager` won't work with `DialogFragment`s. `ViewPager` works by manipulating child `View`s attached directly to it. In a `DialogFragment`, the `View` is in a `Dialog`, in a completely separate window.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I understand it's a bit of a round peg square hole situation. The problem is figuring out if there's a slipper that fits or whether I should start building a square shoe... Have you encountered this problem before? Do you know what a more established approach might be?

Comment: I've got a much better implementation now. Don't use that shaky code I linked you before. I'll get you an example here in a little while. Hope you didn't spend too much time on that.

Comment: Interested to see it! I had a good play around with it but I wasn't able to come up with anything which quite achieved what I was after. In terms of the layout of the original code it was spot on despite the restricted dimensions. I've decided to study a bit deeper before having another crack. On that note would you recommend any learning materials? As of today I'm leafing through Professional Android Development by Reto Meier and Ian Lake. I've already worked through a few (some much) older books (Head First Java, Head First Design Patterns, Beginning Android Application Development).

Comment: I also use tutorials on the android developer site and trawl android docs when I can. Not to mention stackoverflow and general Googling. But if you have any further recommendations for a relatively new dev I'm keen to learn more! Anyway, I probably shouldn't abuse the comments section too much...

Comment: Hey, sorry, your comments got lost in my flooded inbox. I don't really know of any particular resources to recommend, other than the official documentation and samples, and here, of course. I just picked it up from various places as I went. I'm not one for any kind of structured learning, these days. Anyhoo, I'm putting the finishing touches on my new example right now. Hopefully have it ready in about an hour.

Comment: OK, give this a whirl: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aea7tZ9mt9wUxHg_O8QkdVl2jGON7KYh/view?usp=drivesdk. I'm pretty happy with it. Gimme a shout if you have any issues getting it working.

Comment: Just had a browse through the code you wrote as I've had a busy couple of days. Looks good and definitely couldn't have reached that solution any time soon by myself! Time for me to dive a little deeper I think. I'll test it out when I get the chance, hopefully some point this evening. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome solution! I haven't had time to play around with it too much yet but looks promising from the demo. Only minor issues I (well, android studio) noticed on typing up were the WindowManager in the Adapter class (getSystemService method requires API > 23 so potential backwards compatibility issue?) and the LayoutInflater in the same class which isn't accessed.

Comment: Oh, yeah, no, it's just that particular `getSystemService()` overload that's 23+. You can use `winManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);` instead. And just remove the `LayoutInflater`. It was left over from earlier testing.

Comment: Just noticed a subtle difference between this pager and the regular. I'm guessing you were probably aware but incase you hadn't noticed already, when you attempt to swipe 'out of bounds' with the regular pager there's usually a brief animation to show that you can't scroll any further.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I disabled that. Thought it looked weird, having an overscroll effect hovering in empty space. It's the `android:overScrollMode="never"` attribute on the `<RecyclerView>` in `pager_dialog`.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, unlike the regular pager the anim doesn't extend the full length of the screen

Comment: Yeah, I thought about trying to get that full height, but I'm pretty sure that's gonna take some heavy lifting. If I ever figure out a simple, elegant solution to that, I'll let ya know.

Comment: Likewise... perhaps a dummy full screen pager which is entirely transparent and runs in tandem would at least give the desired effect.

Comment: I don't really like adding extra `View`s to a hierarchy for a single property. I'd much rather port the overscroll effect into a custom `FrameLayout` that we can use as the holder for the `RecyclerView`. I'm gonna do some research on it later.

Comment: OK, I've flip-flopped. I'm using ViewPager again. Like most of my custom UI stuff, it usually takes a few iterations before I get one that covers all the minutiae. Sorry if this throws you, but I think I've hit all the points with this one. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klA14fpzpa5sKRZXS5vkKLpcyCXvpzrV/view?usp=drivesdk. I'll leave the link for the RecyclerView implementation, in case you can use any of that. Cheers!

Comment: Latest iteration looks great! The only missing xml attribute I noticed was the scrimColor but I figured that'd be the same as the previous iteration. The app I'm working on at the moment has several themes and I'm a little unsure how to set the Pager's theme to change with the other activities / fragments. Haven't had too much of a think about it yet but I'm out of time for today so I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to set the style of the pager for each theme by setting the style on the instance of the pager called in the main activity. However, the darkening effect doesn't extend to the status bar, which remains the same color and has a bit of a jarring effect.

Comment: DialogFragment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QsV74SO_DTVMZjYQQ8EQOmspKvv44orc


PagerVersion: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F2NREO6zDBOW0tYq5yaro3NjU52yRJbc

Comment: Finally sussed the issue! Turns out it was a fairly easy fix. Instead of setting individual styles from the instance of `MyPagerDialogFragment`, I simply set the parent style for `Pager.Dialog` to `AppTheme.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184504/discussion-between-josh-hardman-and-mike-m).